# Trying to build a round circle with glow effect in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface

[Round Bar with glow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIZlA.png) I am trying to build a custom circle in flutter with a neon like glow but can't seem to get it right.

It doesn't have to be anything fancy but would be great if I can animate the glow to pulse but I do need text in the middle which I should get right. I have tried SFRadialGuage with no success.

Some advice on how to get this right would be great!

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Sorry Newbie here, I didn't think it was necessary, I am in between trying my own custom rounded box and the SFRadiulGauge package, just give me 10 minutes and Ill modify the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Avatar glow package
https://pub.dev/packages/avatar_glow

```
AvatarGlow(
                  glowColor: Color(0xff39FF14),    //Neon Color
                  endRadius: 130.0,

                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
                  repeat: true,
                  showTwoGlows: true,
                  repeatPauseDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),

                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 80,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    child: Image(image: AssetImage("your image path"),
                        width: 140,
                        height: 140),
                  ),
                ),
```